# Swift Package Manager XCode 13.1 Could not find module 'xxx' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'

Tags: build, swift-package-manager, xcode13

As many other somewhat similar issues reported, having problem building for simulator on M1 Macbook, trying to see if anyone has resolved this. Including my own framework using Swift Package Manager. There is nothing special about it other than it is a swift framework which builds fine on its own. Everything else builds fine it just seems that for whatever reason I can not force to build this package for x86_64 arch.

1. Open XCode using Rosetta works - but it is a hack and a work around I would think with performance issues
2. Building for device works
3. Attempted to change build settings as follows:
   [image]

I have also tried to set "Build active architecture only" to NO

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, it seems like the package manager has a problem that has not been resolved by Apple yet

Comment: Still no luck with Xcode 13.4 RC…

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any luck in excluding the architectures for SPM packages ?

Comment: Still seems to be a problem with Xcode 14. Tested with 14.0 beta 2

Comment: Any ideas on work arounds?

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/force-xcode-to-produce-universal-spm-dependency-builds/50747/5